# I have a ListView, can I send all the information to one TextView and only display the information based on the OnItemClick?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, textview, switch-statement

I have a ListView. It contains JSON I pulled from the web. I want each item in the ListView to go to the **same** activity and the **same** TextView. That's easy enough on the face of it.

However I want the TextView to show different items depending on what the user clicked on. In fact better make it two TextViews because one of them has a link. There's two lines of text, one is a link.

So if the user presses the first list item, they go to this activity and be presented with information_01. If the same user backs out and then goes to the second list item it should go to the very same activity and show information_02, and so on.

I'll show you what I have so far, it's nothing special:

```
title.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                  switch (position) {
                  case 0:
                      Driver p = (Driver) title.getItemAtPosition(position);
                      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
                      i.putExtra("one_id", p.id);
                      i.putExtra("one_link", p.link);
                      MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                  case 1:
                      Driver p1 = (Driver) title.getItemAtPosition(position);
                      Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
                      i1.putExtra("two_id", p1.id);
                      i1.putExtra("two_link", p1.link);
                      MainActivity.this.startActivity(i1);
                  case 2:
                      break;
                  }
```

Hopefully this is possible because creating a million activities for each list item is a pain in the arse. Like I said one of them is a link which I need to send to another page on my app. So please bare in mind that showing it and clicking on it is needed.

Would great appreciate some help on the matter. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My DataActivity.class

```
public class DataActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_list);

    //Case 0
    Intent intent0 = getIntent();
    String link0 = intent0.getStringExtra("one_link");
    String id0 = intent0.getStringExtra("one_id");

    TextView data0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.case0Text);
    data0.setText("ID: " + id0 + "\n\n Click here: " + link0);

    //Case 1
    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    String id1 = intent1.getStringExtra("two_id");
    String link1 = intent1.getStringExtra("two_link");

    TextView data1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.case1Text);
    data1.setText("ID: " + id1 + "\n\n Click here: " + link1);
}
}
```

Comment: post code of `DataActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {

            Driver driver = (Driver) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("one_id", driver.id);
                intent.putExtra("one_link", driver.link);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I don't know how but it worked. I guess the parent is the ListView and yeah, gets the onClick from there. Do you know how I could do it if I wanted to make a link where one_link shows up?

Comment: @RED_ if somethings helpful and solve your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Of course. Is there potential for an onClick on the information I send to that activity though? Just so I know this can work and I wont need to change it.

Comment: @RED_ No need to write switch() statement, this is enough to pass the value of selected index of List. So only one key is required not two_id,two_link and so on.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you storing your json data? Store it in an hashmap and retreive it based on the position of itemclick method, you dont have to do this much of things .

Comment: It gets pulled, I put it in an ArrayList, the ArrayList converts it to a ListView. Wouldn't even know where to begin with HashMpas

Comment: can you post your code , how you are storing the json data in arraylist, what kind of data you are storing.

Comment: I actually posted a question earlier about it because I was not understand the idea of storing it in the ListView. Check the last question I made. Looks like Amits answer worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
title.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {


                  Driver p = (Driver) title.getItemAtPosition(position);
                  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("id", p.id);
                  i.putExtra("link", p.link);

              }
```

DataActivity.class

```
  public class DataActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data_list);

    //Case 0
    Intent intent0 = getIntent();
    String link0 = intent0.getStringExtra("link");
    String id0 = intent0.getStringExtra("id");

    TextView data0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.case0Text);
    data0.setText("ID: " + id0 + "\n\n Click here: " + link0);


}
}
```

You can take two textView in DataActivity's xml, one for id `id` and one for link and make link's textview clickable, and set a clickListener on it.

Comment: Amit gave an answer that worked but I'll keep this in mind because it looks similar. Got to make it show different things now based on each link which is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: When I mean I need one of the TextViews to be clickable I mean they are going to have to go to the same Activity also (Information.class), but in that activity different data will be shown. I guess it can be done in a ListView since there is clear list but not in a TextView it's just one thing over and over.